# About Legendre square expansion for $\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus

How it possible to  show the following equality:
$$\cos \left(\sqrt{x^2-1} z\right)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{P_n(x){}^2 \left(\pi ^{3/2} \left(-\frac{1}{16}\right)^n z^{2 n} \Gamma (n+1) \, _2F_3\left(n+1,n+1;n+\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2},2 n+2;\frac{z^2}{4}\right)\right)}{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3}
$$
I have verified numerically it seems to work; can we show equality by differentiating or integrating both expressions?

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: Sorry i found a error but I have edit the formula works fine , 10 term gives an erro about 10^-35-